# Running the XCode 3.1 application in XCode 4.1?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am new developer on iPhone. My problem is that I have installed the XCode 4.1 after changed the settings in the edit project settings it shows XCode 3.1 is missing so if any one know about it give me solution to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set the base SDK version in project settings and Target settings as well.
you should check if you have specified the base SDK at both places.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

click on your project under project navigator. then go to build settings
change the base SDK to your 4.x. do it in both project and target.

Answer (score 1):

See "To Edit a Build Setting…":

> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Building/Building.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH9-SW5